# Android, How to rotate recorded video using MediaRecorder in portrait mode

Tags: android, video, orientation, mediarecorder, portrait

I am trying to capture video in a custom view. I can display video in correct orientation via Camera.setDisplayOrientation(rotation), but recorded video is still in landscape mode. I cannot capture video correctly in portrait mode.

I tested https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video  and it has the same problem too.

I am calling `setCameraOrientation()` method after `Camera.open(currentCameraId)` after checking for permissions.

```
private void setCameraOrientation()
{
    int rotation = getRotation();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setRotation(rotation);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}

private int getRotation()
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = 0;
    switch (display.getRotation())
    {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            rotation = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            rotation = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            rotation = 270;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            rotation = 180;
            break;
    }
    return rotation;
}
```

This lets me display video in correct orientation. But when after I stop `MediaRecorder` and check for saved file, I see 90 degrees rotated video with bad aspect ratio. I checked this via pulling to my computer and in another fragment which has VideoView element. My  prepareRecorder method is:

```
private boolean prepareRecorder()
{
    mCamera.lock();
    mCamera.unlock();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    if (!mIsMute)
    {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setProfile(profile);
    }
    else
    {
        recorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
        recorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
        recorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
        recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
    }

    recorder.setMaxDuration(maxVideoDuration - videoProgress);

    String fileName = StorageUtil.sharedUtil().getExternalStorageDir() + File.separator + String.format(
            fileNameFormat, videoCount);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);

    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

    try
    {
        recorder.prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and then I just call `recorder.start();`

By the way I tried `recorder.setOrientationHint(90);` just before `recoreder.prepare();` but it does not do anything. I can display correct orientation but cannot save.

Comment: right after `recorder.setCamera()` add `recorder.setOrientationHint(rotationDegrees);`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need.  Portrait mode worked for me.  The only difference in my code vs. yours is that I don't set rotation in the CameraParameters, just `setDisplayOrientation` on the camera and `mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);`

`// Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    // parameters.setRotation(rotation);
    // mCamera.setParameters(parameters);`

I have the right orientation now, but somehow, the recorded video has a strange meta-data, a square aspect ratio.  So, some more work to do there.  Will post update.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Here is the code that I have for handling the rotation on recording. This is using the camera api and not the camera2 api:

```
 private void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraId, info);
        int rotation = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Orientation: " + String.valueOf(result));

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this is not exactly my problem. I am already setting display orientation with `setCameraOrientation()` method. This helps me to display correctly while recording but my problem is to save video in portrait mode. 

It always saves video in landscape mode and I am using ffmpeg to rotate the video which costs me additional time (a few seconds).

I am testing with General Mobile Android One with Android7.0 OS.

Comment: why are you using ffmpeg to rotate the videos? The correct rotation should be in the metadata of the video when it is record. Is that not happening?

Comment: I record a video and then play it in next screen. If I do not rotate it plays video in wrong orientation. At first I thought it was related with my player in Android but then I pulled the .mp4 video to my computer and result was the same. Video played -90 degrees wrong orientation. I could solve this issue only with rotating video with ffmpeg.

Comment: When you record the video without using ffmpeg after, is the rotation correct on the video?

Comment: no it is not. that's my problem. I record video in portrait orientation but orientation is wrong after video is saved. For example in video details video width is greater than height

Comment: What do you see in the metadata for the video file? Can you use MediaInfo (https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) to see what is set there? I think you are getting the video recorded correctly, but perhaps there is something with the rotation in the metadata that might be off.